# How can i achieve this type of custom tab design in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: I am trying to design like this below image in flutter.]

I am trying to design like this image in flutter.

Comment: if you can make rounded rectangle tab items, that's basically it. just make the color of selected tab as that of page background.It will look exactly like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are some basic properties provided in the `TabBar` but the are not enough in your use case.
You have to create a `TabController` and an index variable. Whenever the switch happened `TabController` have to set the index & background of the tab is needs to be set according to that index.

**Editing my code for more optimise answer with border radius**

Example Code

```
class _TabDemoState extends State<TabDemo> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController _tabController;

  int _selectedTab = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);

    _tabController.addListener((){
      if (!_tabController.indexIsChanging){
        setState(() {
          _selectedTab = _tabController.index; 
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Tab Demo"),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 3,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Material(
                color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                child: TabBar(
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue,
                  labelColor: Colors.blue,
                  indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                  controller: _tabController,
                  labelPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  tabs: [
                    _getTab(0, Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                    _getTab(1, Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                    _getTab(2, Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: TabBarView(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: _tabController,
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.directions_car),
                    Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                    Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }


  _getTab(index, child) {
    return Tab(
      child: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Container(
          child: child,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color:
                  (_selectedTab == index ? Colors.white : Colors.grey.shade300),
              borderRadius: _generateBorderRadius(index)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _generateBorderRadius(index) {
    if ((index + 1) == _selectedTab)
      return BorderRadius.only(bottomRight: Radius.circular(10.0));
    else if ((index - 1) == _selectedTab)
      return BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0));
    else
      return BorderRadius.zero;
  }
}
```

**Note** - In this I have faced an issue. Its when you fast swipe on from left to right that `_tabContoller` values returns two values first it gives you `index-2` value than `index-1` value which is expected. I don't know why this is happening but to resolve this issue I have to disable the scroll on `TabBarView`.

Comment: Thanks it's working perfect for me.

Comment: perfect! is there any way to animated the tab change like in segmentedcontrol?